# How to show comments from different Plugins to same post type?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, comments, email, wp-insert-post

I have two different comments, but both are related to the same post type.
The first comments in this way:

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit_tickets'])){
        $tickets_reply =  $_POST['tickets_reply'];
            $my_tickets_comment_data = array(
                'comment_post_ID' => $post->ID,
                'comment_content' => $tickets_reply,
                'comment_author' => $current_user->display_name,
                'comment_author_email' => $current_user->user_email,
                'comment_type' => 'comment',
                'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
                'comment_date' => get_the_date(),
                'comment_approved' => 1,
            );
                $commentid  = wp_insert_comment($my_tickets_comment_data);
    }
```

And this is how the second comment in the same post type looks:

```php
                $comment_array = array(
                    'comment_content' => $mail['body'],
                    'comment_post_ID' => $posts[0]->ID,
                    'comment_author'  => ucwords(strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<',true)),
                    'comment_author_email' => preg_replace('~[<>]~', '', strstr($mail['header']->fromaddress, '<')),
                    'comment_type'  => 'comment',
                    'comment_date'  => $mail['header']->Date,
                    'comment_approved' => 1,
                    'comment_meta'  => array(
                        'message_id' => preg_replace('~[<]~','',strstr($mail['header']->message_id, '@',true))),
                );
               $commentid =  wp_insert_comment($comment_array);
            }
```

This is how I display the comments:

```php
/*get replies*/         
    $args = array(
        'user_id' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        'type' => 'comment'     
    );      
$get_tickets_replies = get_comments($args);
    function filter_media_comment_status( $open, $post_id ) {
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        if( $post->post_type == 'my-post-type' ) {
        return false;
   }
    return $open;
}
add_filter( 'comments_open', 'filter_media_comment_status', 10 , 2 );
    ?>              
<div class="reply-detail">
    <?php foreach ($get_tickets_replies as $replies) { ?>
    <div class="avatar-message user-message">
    <div class="panel-image user">
    <img class="avatar" alt="Avatar"src="//www.gravatar.com/avatar/394b69f87b5e402481cbf8ce069ce8ac?s=80&amp;d=mm">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading user"> 
    <!---<?php echo ($replies->comment_date_gmt); ?>--->
                                        
    <h6><?php echo ($replies->comment_author); ?></h6>
    <span class="date"><b>Posted:</b> <?php echo date('F j, Y'); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-reply user">
    <p><?php echo $replies->comment_content; ?></p>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php   }  ?>
```

The display code (above) and first comments are in the same file, or you can say the same plugin, and the second plugin is inserting comments from emails, and both comments are inserted to the same post type.

In the first plugin, the comments can be inserted from the frontend or backend. But in the second plugin, the comments are email replies. Both the plugin use the same custom post type, but the second plugin only deals with emails, whereas in the first plugin the post is created manually from the WP dashboard.

You can see the two different `wp_insert_comment()` calls and their arrays/args.

Now my question is, the display code only works for the first comment, so how can I display the second comments?

Comment: I edited your post to clarifiy the question based on your comments, but if you noticed any mistakes in the wording I used, just edit your post and correct the mistakes.. also, I've deleted my previous comments, so you should delete yours, too.

Comment: ok, It is all fine. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: So I wanted to confirm one thing: Right now, your display code is displaying comments by the currently logged-in user, right? And the comments from the 2nd plugin do not have a *user ID*, only email as the unique identifier; is that correct? If so, is there something that can "connect" the current user with the emails (the "second comments")? (maybe a special user meta?) If no, then I don't see how would it be possible to display the emails when the `user_id` argument is set in your `$args`.

Comment: However, if you wanted to have two display divs/areas - one for displaying the first comments and the other for the second comments, then that one might be possible.

Comment: The 2nd plugin works with email. The posts are email posts and the comments are email replies also the users are also created when emails are inserted as post. So, when or if the comments are displayed in the frontend it will show the user who sent the email. 
And displaying the first comments and second comments separately won't help as the comments in the email post can be both email replies or from the first plugin as well.

Comment: I understand. But I don't see in your code how are you assigning the user ID to the emails (or comments from the 2nd plugin), and as you've tested it for yourself, only when you removed the `user_id` from `$args`, then the second comments appeared alongside the first comments. Which means, the current user did not have any second comments. So are you *certain* you've correctly assigned the user to their respective email comments?

Comment: And for debugging purposes, you could try adding this before the `/*get replies*/` - `global $wpdb; $data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT comment_author, comment_content FROM $wpdb->comments WHERE user_id = " . (int) $current_user->ID . " AND comment_type = 'comment'" ); var_dump( $data );` - does the output include the second comments?

Comment: Yes, it outputs the second comments.

Comment: And does it still output the second comments if you change the `AND comment_type = 'comment'"` to `AND comment_type = 'comment' AND comment_post_ID = " . (int) $post->ID` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't output the second comment when changing the `AND comment_type = 'comment'"`

Comment: Then you know what that implies, don't you? So if `var_dump( $post->ID );` does output the correct post ID, then the current user does not have second comments for *that post*. So as I said in the 1st place, you already have the code for displaying the second comments - you just need to ensure your data are being inserted/setup correctly.. and adjust your `$args` accordingly :) So if the user should actually have some second comments, then ensure the post ID is correctly set when you *insert the comment*.